# Power BI - SUM IFF Across two (not related) tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I need help about Power bi.
PROBLEM:
I have two tables (most of the fields in the tables are the same, but tables are not equal) , I have Unit name in both tables, and I need a table (output) that contains each Unit and the COUNT of the unit (how many time that unit is in table 1 and in table 2) based on 2 conditions:

- I have to count only units that have status not equal to "rejected".
- I have to count only units that have the Department_Name = "TX"

I used this DAX measure (but it didn't work):

```
Measure = calculate(
COUNT(Table 1[Unit_Name]) + COUNT(Table 2[Unit_Name]),
Table 1[Status] <> "rejected",
Table 2[Status] <> "rejected",
Table 1[Department_Name] <> "TX",
Table 2[Department_Name] <> "TX")
```

The purpose is to use the measure in a PowerBI chart and insert on the X axis the measure, on the Y axis the unit_name (I don't know if I have to use unit_name by Table 1 or unit_name by table 2).
I also tried to create a connection between tables using unit_name as primary key.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEvWQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do that but the quickest and easiest way is to merge the two tables in to one like

go into the power Query editor , and merge the two tables into one using Power Query Script
for details on how to merge the two tbale data set in power Query see the below link :
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/merge-two-tables-in-power-bi/

video tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cX62HBIZdPA

after doing this your table will be one instead of 2 tables and you can easily perform the count on single column "Department Name" for the Unit occurance.

Comment: the tables have different structure, if I merge them, the data will not follow the structure they have in the previous two tables before merging

Comment: the picture you attached containing 2 tables have exactly same structure so I baseline them , but if you have different structures thats not the issue , issue will be when you have different granularity of each table.

kindly attach the exact structure example then.

Answer (score 0):

Using DAX, It is a 2 step process:

First Create a new table with this DAX Code:

```
FullJoin = UNION(Table1,Table2)
```

Your Table will look like this:

[image: FullJoin]

Then Create a measure with DAX Code like this:

```
Solution = CALCULATE(
COUNTX(FullJoin,[Unit_Name]),
FullJoin[Status] <> "rejected",
FullJoin[Department_Name] = "TX"
)
```

Now If we test it on a visual,

[image: DFs]

Comment: @AB-cd I updated the answer. Please check it.